# Detecting when ChucK child shred has finished

Tags: chuck

Is it possible to determine when a ChucK child shred has finished executing if you have a reference to the child shred?  For example, in this code:

```
// define function go()
fun void go()
{
    // insert code
}

// spork another, store reference to new shred in offspring
spork ~ go() => Shred @ offspring;
```

Is it possible to determine when `offspring` is done executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say so, let me quote from the "VERSIONS" file from the latest release;

```
  - (added) int Shred.done()  // is the shred done?
            int Shred.running()  // is the shred running?
```

I'm not 100% sure what "running" is supposed to refer to (perhaps I misunderstand it?) but  "done" seems to suit your needs;

================== 8<================

```
fun void foo()
    {
    second => now;
    }

spork ~ foo() @=> Shred bar;

<<<bar.done()>>>;
<<<bar.running()>>>; // why is this 0? Bug?
2::second => now;
<<<bar.done()>>>;
<<<bar.running()>>>;
```

==========8<======================

Please note that calling these on a Shred object with no shred process attached to it will return more or less random numbers which is probably a bug.

---Answer from Kassen on [chuck-users mailing list](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/mailman/listinfo/chuck-users).